# How to merge first 3 columns for rows with same value in PDF

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, itext

I'm using `itextSharp` to export a DataTable to a pdf table. I can export the data to a pdf table using the sample code i have posted below. The DataTable contains close to 21 columns.

The first column in the pdf (DataTable) might contain similar values for any number of rows. If the data values in first column for a group of rows is similar, i want to merge the first 3 columns of those rows as one cell.

I'm having trouble modifying the code below to achieve this.

```
public iTextSharp.text.Table GetItextTable(DataTable dtChartData, string reportType)
    {
        int intCols = dtChartData.Columns.Count; //Total number of columns 
        int intRows = dtChartData.Rows.Count; //Total number of rows 
        iTextSharp.text.Table pdfTable = new iTextSharp.text.Table(intCols, intRows);
        try
        {
            pdfTable.BorderWidth = 1;
            pdfTable.Width = 100;
            pdfTable.Padding = 1;
            pdfTable.Spacing = 1;
            /*creating table headers */
            for (int i = 0; i < intCols; i++)
            {

                iTextSharp.text.Cell cellCols = new iTextSharp.text.Cell();
                iTextSharp.text.Font ColFont = iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.GetFont("Tahoma", 07,
                    iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD);
                for (int l = 0; l < dtChartData.Columns.Count; l++)
                {
                    if (dtChartData.Columns[l].ColumnName.Contains("_"))
                    {
                        dtChartData.Columns[l].ColumnName = dtChartData.Columns[l].ColumnName.Replace("_", " ");
                    }
                }
                iTextSharp.text.Chunk chunkCols = new iTextSharp.text.Chunk(dtChartData.Columns[i].ColumnName,ColFont);
                cellCols.HorizontalAlignment = iTextSharp.text.Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                if ((chunkCols.ToString().ToLower() == "ReportDetails"))
                {
                    cellCols.HorizontalAlignment = iTextSharp.text.Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                }
            }
            /* loop that take values from every row in datatable and insert in itextsharp table */
            for (int k = 0; k < intRows; k++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < intCols; j++)
                {
                    iTextSharp.text.Cell cellRows = new iTextSharp.text.Cell();
                    iTextSharp.text.Font RowFont = iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.GetFont("Tahoma", 07);
                    iTextSharp.text.Chunk chunkRows = new iTextSharp.text.Chunk(dtChartData.Rows[k][j].ToString(),RowFont);

                    cellRows.HorizontalAlignment = iTextSharp.text.Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                    cellRows.Add(chunkRows);
                    pdfTable.AddCell(cellRows);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //error handling code here removed
        }
        return pdfTable;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to change the `Colspan`?

```
iTextSharp.text.Cell cell = new iTextSharp.text.Cell();
cell.AddElement(new Paragraph("colspan 3"));
cell.Colspan = 3;
table.AddCell(cell);
```

In this case, `cell` will span three columns.

Comment: the trouble i'm having is the logic to check if the rows first column have the same value.

Comment: That's not iTextSharp's problem. iTextSharp won't do that check for you. Checking if a string `a` is identical to a string `b`, and if that string `b` is identical to string `c`, shouldn't be a problem. What have you tried? Why didn't it work?

Comment: I agree with Bruno. I'd further add that at this stage I'd recommend halting your usage of iTextSharp temporarily. Instead, focus solely on the `DataTable`. If its coming from a SQL system you might be able to throw some SQL logic at it to get it how you want. If you're only in C#, then make a quick WinForm or ASP.Net WebForm view over your `DataTable` and apply whatever logic you need. Once you've got that you can easily snap it into your posted code to work with iTextSharp.

Answer (score 0):

try this. i just edited your code, not checked

here i have edited 1 line of your code and added a new line (total 2 lines of change only).

dont forget to combine headding row like this, if you need

```
/* loop that take values from every row in datatable and insert in itextsharp table */
        for (int k = 0; k < intRows; k++)
        {
            for (int j = 2; j < intCols; j++)// EDIT: if all first 3 cols are same, then starts with 2
            { 
                iTextSharp.text.Cell cellRows = new iTextSharp.text.Cell();
                if(j == 2) cellRows.Colspan = 3;// ADD: it'll gives a 3 times long cell
                iTextSharp.text.Font RowFont = iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.GetFont("Tahoma", 07);
                iTextSharp.text.Chunk chunkRows = new iTextSharp.text.Chunk(dtChartData.Rows[k][j].ToString(),RowFont);

                cellRows.HorizontalAlignment = iTextSharp.text.Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                cellRows.Add(chunkRows);
                pdfTable.AddCell(cellRows);
            }
        }
```