# iTextSharp NET PDF library exclude/remove columns based on values in table cells

Tags: c#, itext, windows-forms-designer

[table iText Sharp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFWWc.png)

I'm trying to figure out how to remove/exclude columns if all values in the column cells are == 0.

This is what I have so far:

```
private void button10_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        try
        {
            Document doc = null;

            // Sets the document to A4 size and rotates it so that the     orientation of the page is Landscape.
            doc = new Document(PageSize.A3.Rotate(), 0, 0, 50, 50);

            PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd"), FileMode.Create));
            BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA_BOLD, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
            iTextSharp.text.Font font = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bf, 18);
            BaseFont body = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
            iTextSharp.text.Font fontbody = new iTextSharp.text.Font(body, 12);
            wri.PageEvent = new PDFFooter2();

            doc.Open(); //Öppna dokument för att skriva
                        // Skriv något

            var datum = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString();
            Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph("PACKRAPPORT " + datum, font);

            paragraph.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;

            doc.Add(paragraph);

            iTextSharp.text.Font fontTable = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);

            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 2);

            table.SpacingBefore = 45f;
            table.TotalWidth = 300;
            table.DefaultCell.Phrase = new Phrase() { Font = fontTable };

            for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1; j++)
            {
                if (dataGridView1.Columns[j].Name == "Id")
                {
                    //Skip this column
                    continue;
                }

                table.AddCell(new Phrase(dataGridView1.Columns[j].HeaderText, fontbody));
            }

            table.HeaderRows = 1;

            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1; k++)
                {
                    if (dataGridView1.Columns[k].Name == "Id")
                    {
                        //Skip this column
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (dataGridView1[k, i].Value != null)
                    {
                        table.AddCell(new Phrase(dataGridView1[k, i].Value.ToString(), fontbody));
                    }
                }
}

private void button10_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        try
        {
            Document doc = null;

            // Sets the document to A4 size and rotates it so that the     orientation of the page is Landscape.
            doc = new Document(PageSize.A3.Rotate(), 0, 0, 50, 50);

            PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd"), FileMode.Create));
            BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA_BOLD, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
            iTextSharp.text.Font font = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bf, 18);
            BaseFont body = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
            iTextSharp.text.Font fontbody = new iTextSharp.text.Font(body, 12);
            wri.PageEvent = new PDFFooter2();

            doc.Open(); //Öppna dokument för att skriva
                        // Skriv något

            var datum = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString();
            Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph("PACKRAPPORT " + datum, font);

            paragraph.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;

            doc.Add(paragraph);


            iTextSharp.text.Font fontTable = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);

            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 2);

            table.SpacingBefore = 45f;
            table.TotalWidth = 300;
            table.DefaultCell.Phrase = new Phrase() { Font = fontTable };

            for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1; j++)
            {
                if (dataGridView1.Columns[j].Name == "Id")
                {
                    //Skip this column
                    continue;
                }

                table.AddCell(new Phrase(dataGridView1.Columns[j].HeaderText, fontbody));
            }

            table.HeaderRows = 1;

            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1; k++)
                {
                    if (dataGridView1.Columns[k].Name == "Id")
                    {
                        //Skip this column
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (dataGridView1[k, i].Value != null)
                    {
                        table.AddCell(new Phrase(dataGridView1[k, i].Value.ToString(), fontbody));
                    }
                }
}
```

Comment: Please read [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36568392/how-to-merge-first-3-columns-for-rows-with-same-value-in-pdf#comment60752977_36568465) by @ChrisHaas

Comment: Thanks @ChrisHaas I changed my logic in the datatable Before send it to the dataGridview and now iText works as I want to :)